# Attempting to extract one of two possible words from a text string if matches a criteria, or input the string in it's entirety

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2010

I'm trying to bring back one of two possible words (Local or National) from a text string, and if neither of these words are in the text string, then bring back the string in the whole cell

The issue I have is that I can bring back either word when they appear, but I get an error when they do not

I'm currently using

```
  =IFERROR(IF(SEARCH("*local*",B2,1),"Local"),IF(SEARCH("*national*",B2,1),"National"))
```

However this obviously this doesn't bring back if the words not exist

I'm sure it's easy and I'm missing something, but I just cannot figure it out.  any help would be great

Cheers all

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use:

[image]

Formula in `B1`:

```
=IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("*local*",A1)),"Local",IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("*national*",A1)),"national",A1))
```

Drag down

***Note:***

Notice that your wildcards make it that even a string with 'international' in it will return 'national'. If this is not what you want, you should remove the wildcards.

Comment: Worked perfectly.  Yes aware of the *National* wild card, thanks for pointing it though

Answer (score 1):

You can also use INDEX/AGGREGATE:

```
=IFERROR(INDEX({"local","national"},AGGREGATE(15,7,ROW($1:$2)/(ISNUMBER(SEARCH({"local";"national"},A1))),1)),A1)
```

This will allow one to replace the both hard coded arrays with a range of cells that contain the outputs.  If `Local` and `National` were in D1:D2 then you can use:

```
=IFERROR(INDEX($D:$D,AGGREGATE(15,7,ROW($D$1:$D$2)/(ISNUMBER(SEARCH($D$1:$D$2,A1))),1)),A1)
```

That way if the list gets bigger the formula does not.

[image]

Comment: Thanks @scott Craner, haven't needed to use it, but will reference it for future use

Answer (score 0):

**I'd suggest regular expressions.**

```
=IF(REGEXMATCH(A2,"(Local|National)"),REGEXEXTRACT(A2,"(Local|National)"),A2)
```

[image: regular expressions in excel]

Comment: The OP tagged Excel